# Dynamic links for different pages

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I want to generate a list of items by using a `for` loop. The items list will appear under the heading element in a drop down menu.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="container div_scroll">
<?php if($data->results()){

?>
<div class="row">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading ">
<h4 class="panel"> <?php echo $state_decode . ' : ' . count($data -> results()); ?>
</h4>
</div>

<table class="table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col-md-1">S.N.</th>
<th class="col-md-1">ENQ No</th>
<th class="col-md-1">ENQ Date</th>
<th class="col-md-3">ENQ Descr</th>
<th class="col-md-1">Tender Ref</th>
<th class="col-md-2">Cust Name</th>
<th class="col-md-2">Project Name </th>
<th class="col-md-1">Action</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
switch($state) {
 case "draft" :
  $heading = 'Edit';
  $url = array('new_eis_form1.php','http://google.com');
  $menu = array('Modify','Attach Files','Add Equipment');
  $param = '';
  $btn = array('btn btn-info','btn btn-info','btn btn-info');
  $id_name = 'enq';
  break;
 case "submit" :
  $url = 'http://google.com';
  $action = 'View';
  $param = '';

  break;
  break;
 case "recvd" :
  $url = 'new_eis_form1.php';
  $action = 'Edit';
  $param = '';
  break;

 case "not_recvd" :
  $url = 'new_eis_form1.php';
  $action = 'Edit';
  $param = '';
  break;
 case "hold" :
  $url = 'new_eis_form1.php';
  $action = 'Edit';
  $param = '';
  break;

 case "wo1_pend" :
  $url = 'new_eis_form1.php';
  $action = 'Edit';
  $param = '';
  break;
 case "cancel" :
  $url = 'new_eis_form1.php';
  $action = 'Edit';
  $param = '';
  break;
}

foreach ($data -> results() as $test) {
 $param = $test -> ENQ_NO;
 echo "<tr>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">" . ++$slno . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">" . $test -> ENQ_NO . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">" . $test -> ENQ_DATE . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-3\">" . $test -> ENQ_DESR . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">" . $test -> TENDER_REF_NO . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-2\">" . $test -> CUST_NAME . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-2\">" . $test -> PROJ_NAME . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\"><div class=\"dropdown\">
        <button class=\"btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">".$heading."
         <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-th-list\"></span>
        <span class=\"caret\"></span></button>
        <ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-right\">".
        
        for($i=0;$i<count($menu);$i++){echo "<li><a href=\".$url[$i]."?".$id_name."=".$param.\">".oper($menu[$i],$btn[$i])."</a></li>";
        }
        
        "</ul>
        </div></td>
<td class=\"col-md-2\"></td>

</tr>";
 /* oper() function is in coomon.php; uses two inputs one is btn display label and oter is btn style class */
}

// }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<?php }else{ ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading ">
<h4 class="panel">Alert</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-body">
<h4 class="body panel">There is no enquiry; If you want to add enquiry details please <a href="eis_form_eqp.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link "><u>click here</u></span> </a>.</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

But, the problem is that:

1. I am unable to concatenate the `for`-loop here with the string in PHP.
2. I am using HTML inside PHP and not PHP inside HTML because it destroys bootstrap elements functionality.

```html
<td class=\"col-md-1\"><div class=\"dropdown\"> <button class=\"btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">".$heading." <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-th-list\"></span> <span class=\"caret\"></span></button> <ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-right\">". for($i=0;$i<count($menu);$i++){echo "<li><a href=\".$url[$i]."?".$id_name."=".$param.\">".oper($menu[$i],$btn[$i])."</a></li>"; } "</ul> </div></td>
```

Comment: Please post your for loop which contains php code

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: I have pasted full code of the page.

Comment: Re-ordered the paragraphs and spell-checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
$str = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i++) {
    $str .= '<li>
               <a href="' . $url[$i] . '?'.$id_name.'='.$param.'">'. oper($menu[$i],$btn[$i]).'</a>
            </li>';
}

$html = '<td class="col-md-1">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                        type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$heading.'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    ' . $str . '
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, You saved my day

Comment: I same code I am getting "Undefined offset: 2 in E:\Internet\Intra\eq_info\ooplr\eis_enq_status.php on line 191"

Comment: what does that mean and how could i get rid off in this code

Comment: Offset is index in array(). So try to debug. Can you post your line between 185 to 195 pls ?

Comment: Offset in array- it was becoz of all array are not of the same size